# JQuery : Selecting unknown child element

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a dictionary list and I want to access the 2nd child element without knowing what element it is. For example:

```
    <dl>
        <dd>
            <div></div>
            <div></div> (select this item - however can be any html element)
       </dd>
       <dd>
            <div></div>
            <div></div> (select this item - however can be any html element)
       </dd>
       <dd>
            <div></div>
            <div></div> (select this item - however can be any html element)
       </dd>
    </dl>
```

I tried ...

```
    $('dd').each(function() {
        $(this + ':nth-child(2)').addClass('hover');
    }
```

I tried this with a series of different number 0-2 trying to find the element. 0 puts the class in all first child html tags. For example:

```
    <html class="hover">
    <body class="hover">
        <div class="hover">
```

... etc. Not what I want btw. Leading me to believe that $(this) is actually targeting the window and not my individual dd elements.

Anyway if anyone can shed some light I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a `.each()` call - most jQuery functions work happily on lists of elements.

Just match all `.children()` of a `<dd>` that are the 2nd child of their parent, and add the required class:

```
$('dd').children(':nth-child(2)').addClass('hover');
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/TETbE/

or (thanks to @ChrisPratt) you can combine the selectors:

```
$('dd > :nth-child(2)').addClass('hover');
```

Comment: Thanks this worked also. The above answer worked a little better for my implementation however. Thanks again.

Comment: True. But presumably, he simply redacted the code to highlight the point of the question. Otherwise, the most efficient method would actually be `$('dd > :nth-child(2)').addClass('hover');` and he probably would've just done that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt true, if the code is redacted and the `.each()` is doing other stuff too.  Strictly speaking your selector needs a `>` otherwise it'll highlight _any_ descendent that happens to be the second child of its parent.

Comment: That is a good catch because I did notice it doing that as I started to play around with it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is just your syntax. Try:

```
$('dd').each(function() {
    $(':nth-child(2)', this).addClass('hover');
}
```